# AttributeError across TypeError issue in Python 3.2

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm editing the scripts for libtaxii for Python 3.2 since it was written for Python 2.7. I'm working with the following function which writes content blocks to a file. Here's the function:

```
def write_cbs_from_poll_response_11(self, poll_response, dest_dir, write_type_=W_CLOBBER):

    for cb in poll_response.content_blocks:
        if cb.content_binding.binding_id == CB_STIX_XML_10:
            format_ = '_STIX10_'
            ext = '.xml'
        elif cb.content_binding.binding_id == CB_STIX_XML_101:
            format_ = '_STIX101_'
            ext = '.xml'
        elif cb.content_binding.binding_id == CB_STIX_XML_11:
            format_ = '_STIX11_'
            ext = '.xml'
        elif cb.content_binding.binding_id == CB_STIX_XML_111:
            format_ = '_STIX111_'
            ext = '.xml'
        elif cb.content_binding.binding_id == CB_STIX_XML_12:
            format_ = '_STIX12_'
            ext = '.xml'
        else:  # Format and extension are unknown
            format_ = ''
            ext = ''

        if cb.timestamp_label:
            date_string = 't' + cb.timestamp_label.isoformat()
        else:
            date_string = 's' + datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

        filename = gen_filename(poll_response.collection_name,
                                format_,
                                date_string,
                                ext)
        filename = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
        write, message = TaxiiScript.get_write_and_message(filename, write_type_)

        if write:
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write(cb.content)           # The TypeError is thrown here

        print("%s%s" % (message, filename))
```

My current issue is that one of the variables, `cb.content` is throwing a type error:

```
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

This is an easy fix: I used the converter `f.write(cb.content.decode("utf-8"))` in place of the line and then it throws an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

So the interpreter knows it's a string, however it doesn't recognize it?? I'm not really 100% sure.

Thanks in advance to all of you who are smarter than me out there!

Comment: Did you print out the contents of `cb.contents`?

Comment: Possibly the results are from two different iterations of the `for cb in...` loop. Write your code to be able to handle `cb.content` as either a `str` or `bytes` object.

Comment: I did; the contents are able to be printed but I'm assuming that since I'm dealing with an xml file I might have some weird characters in it.

Here's the contents: https://pastebin.com/k2Xed6C9

Comment: You're exactly right, glibdud. The first is a string but the rest are bytes. Good call!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Possibly the results are from two different iterations of the for cb in... loop. Write your code to be able to handle cb.content as either a str or bytes object" -- glibdud

Glibdud was absolutely right. I added in the following in place of f.write(cb.content):

```
if type(cb.content) is str:
    f.write(cb.content)
elif type(cb.content) is bytes:
    f.write(cb.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

And it worked great. Thanks guys!